# How to remove whitespace from above text in a div

Tags: html, css, whitespace

How can I remove whitespace from above and below the text in the div so that the text fits neatly inside the red box.

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>LEX</div>
```

Comment: I'm not getting what you really try to achieve? The whitespace above and below the text seems to be a default whitespace depending on the line-height: https://codepen.io/STWebtastic/pen/NXKvMm If you play with the line-height it removes...Is this what you mean?

Comment: Thanks MrBuggy.  I get your point but I need the text size to be variable and I set it using font-height:  24pt for example.  I don't know how to specify a relative line-height without just using trial and error.

Comment: Is the font-size variable depending on the screen size or something else?

Comment: Do not use 'pt' for screens. 'pt' is for print.

Comment: @Rob was a typo, I meaned px :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fiddling with line-height and em like so:

```
line-height: 1em;
```

This way, whatever your font-size is, the line-height will adjust automagically. 1em might be too much.. perhaps .667em is a better fit?

Comment: Didn't get this, very nice solution and seems to work with the right line-height in em: https://codepen.io/STWebtastic/pen/NXKvMm

Comment: The `em` unit is based on the font-size value of the current element. In this case, if the font-size is 24px, then the line-height will be .667 * 24px = 16px. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length